# Angular count the number of parents for a json object

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of objects. Each object has a property called "**parentLineIndex**". The value of the property is the index of which other object in array is the parent of the object in question.

Sometimes a parent can have its own parent, thus an object will have a parent count of its parent plus its parents parents and so on.

If an object/parent has no parent then "**parentLineIndex**" == -1.

```
    iterate(index, array) {
    let count = 1;
    this.index2 =index;
    this.array2 =array;
  if (this.array2[this.index2].parentLineIndex !== '-1') {
        count++;
        console.log("passed");
        this.iterate(this.array2[this.index2].parentLineIndex, this.array2);

    } else {
        return count;
    }


}
```

I need to determine the count of parents for each object. My thinking is to look if "**parentLineIndex**" == -1. and if not then add one. Using a recursive function. I have tried it but when I call the function recursively, its says that the parameters are undefined.
tool.component.html:107 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentLineIndex' of undefined

```
"editableDocumentLines": [
{
  "text": "AGREEMENT",
  "bulletText": null,
  "page": 1,
  "lineIndex": 0,
  "parentLineIndex": -1
},
{
  "text": "We will provide the insurance described in this policy in return for the premium and compliance with all applicable provisions of this policy.",
  "bulletText": null,
  "page": 1,
  "lineIndex": 1,
  "parentLineIndex": 0
},
{
  "text": "DEFINITIONS",
  "bulletText": null,
  "page": 1,
  "lineIndex": 2,
  "parentLineIndex": -1
},
{
  "text": "In this policy, \"you\" and \"your\" refer to the \"named insured\" shown in the Declarations and the spouse if a resident of the same household. \"We\", \"us\" and \"our\" refer to the Company providing this insurance.",
  "bulletText": "A.",
  "page": 1,
  "lineIndex": 3,
  "parentLineIndex": 2
},
{
  "text": "In addition, certain words and phrases are defined as follows:",
  "bulletText": "B.",
  "page": 1,
  "lineIndex": 4,
  "parentLineIndex": 2
},
{
  "text": "\"Aircraft Liability\", \"Hovercraft Liability\", \"Motor Vehicle Liability\" and \"Watercraft Liability\",",
  "bulletText": "1.",
  "page": 1,
  "lineIndex": 5,
  "parentLineIndex": 4
},
{
  "text": "subject to the provisions in b. below, mean the following:",
  "bulletText": null,
  "page": 1,
  "lineIndex": 6,
  "parentLineIndex": 5
},
{
  "text": "Liability for \"bodily injury\" or \"property damage\" arising out of the:",
  "bulletText": "a.",
  "page": 1,
  "lineIndex": 7,
  "parentLineIndex": 6
},
{
  "text": "Ownership of such vehicle or craft by an \"insured\";",
  "bulletText": "(1)",
  "page": 1,
  "lineIndex": 8,
  "parentLineIndex": 7
},
{
  "text": "Maintenance, occupancy, operation, use, loading or unloading of such vehicle or craft by any person;",
  "bulletText": "(2)",
  "page": 1,
  "lineIndex": 9,
  "parentLineIndex": 7
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lissettdm @Eran. Thank you for your answers, I went with the following :

```
  indexG = 0;

        $scope.increase = function(item) {
            var childHasParent = documentsLines.find(element => element.lineIndex == item);
            if (childHasParent != null) {

                $scope.count[indexG] = $scope.count[indexG] == undefined ? 1 : $scope.count[indexG] + 1;

                var exist = childHasParent.parentLineIndex != -1;

                if (exist) {
                    increase(childHasParent.parentLineIndex);
                }
            } else {
                indexG = 0;
                console.log($scope.count);
                return $scope.count;
            }
        }

        $scope.myFunction =function() {

            documentsLines = json[0].editableDocumentLines;
            $scope.count = [];


            for (i = 0; i < documentsLines.length; i++) {
                item = documentsLines[i];

                if (item.parentLineIndex != -1) {
                    indexG = item.lineIndex;
                    increase(item.parentLineIndex);

                }

            }
            console.log(count)
            return $scope.count;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a flat array and not nested so you can go with `forEach` loop.

```
iterate(array: any[]): number {
  let count = 0;
  array.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.parentLineIndex && obj.parentLineIndex !== -1) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  console.log(count);
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter:

```
const count = iterate.filter(item => item.parentLineIndex && item.parentLineIndex !== -1).length;
```